# Does "going loud" allow you to take the extra demonic form pieces?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

Here are the rules for "Going Loud"

> Going loud allows the demon to completely heal any lethal or
>   bashing damage and shrug off any Tilts affecting her. In addition
>   to this, when the demon goes loud, her current Cover is lost; she
>   replenishes all her Aether, her Primum is set to 10, and she gains
>   access to every Embed her Incarnation gives her affinity for along
>   with all Exploits. Changing this way does not require a normal
>   compromise roll, since it constitutes the ultimate compromise of
>   completely destroying the demon’s current Cover.

and Rules for additional pieces of Demonic Form

> At Primum 3, the demon gains a fourth Modification.
>   At Primum 6 the demon gains a third Techonology, and at
>   Primum 10 the demon gains a second Process.

When a demon goes loud do they gain the additional pieces of the demonic form as if they had attained a natural Primum 10?

Comment: *ker-blink* huh... This is something I haven't thought of. Initial impulse says yes, because you are setting off every red flag possible in the eyes of the God Machine. Let me do some research to see if what I have agrees with me.

Comment: Does it say or suggest anywhere that the setting of Primum to 10 is only temporary?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie going loud itself is temporary so when the effects wear off... I forget where it talks about the duration.

Comment: @xenoterracide The Going Loud is temporary, sure. But does it suggest that anything in that list of "in addition" is temporary? I mean, the Cover being blown and Aether replenishing is obviously not temporary. Gaining access to every Embed and Exploit could be temporary though, that seems more like a temporary bonus from Going Loud than an "instant" lasting effect.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie it doesn't, imho, make sense that you'd get a permanent Primum to 10, the only reason I wrote this question is because it didn't explicitly say what is (apparently) said on p113 inline in what I quoted here, and it was very explicit about other bits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Page 113 of the core book mentions that [The demon's] Primum is set to 10, with *all* the benefits that entails. I'd argue that includes demonic form upgrades.